Are all Starship/Super Heavy "cylinders" 4mm thick?
Source

The bodies of both rocket stages are made from stainless steel[18] and are manufactured by stacking and welding stainless steel cylinders.[19] These cylinders have a diameter of 9 m (30 ft) a height of 1.8 m (5 ft 11 in), a thickness of 4 mm (0.16 in) and a mass of 1,600 kg (3,500 lb) each.[19

Does this apply throughout the stack? Seems odd, because it would mean a dramatic mass penalty.

It would be solidly in keeping with SpaceX's engineering style: mass penalties are acceptable if they keep the overall system cost down.  Being able to use the same raw materials and the same construction jigs for the entire rocket is a good example of "keeping overall system costs down".

There's a much more obvious "dramatic mass penalty" - they're using steel.

Not rigorous enough for an answer... but too long for a comment
The tension load on the tank walls is largely from propellant ullage pressure (maximum 6 bar). This is uniform over the height of the stack. (Add to this the hydrostatic pressure of the propellant for the individual tanks).
The highest compression load is the weight of the full stack on the lowest ring (minus engines, plus launch thrust in excess of weight).
Back-of-the-envelope calculations (which are not rigorous enough for an SE answer) give both the tension and compression loads close to the yield strength of 304SS.
The top of the stack may have a lower compression load than the bottom, but the upper tanks still need the same thickness due to tension loads.
I think SpaceX engineers got it right.

+1  I suspect you know this and only misspoke, but your description of the compression load in your third paragraph is not correct.  For example, if the rocket was hovering (thrust = weight), your description would give a compression load of twice the weight.  The actual compression load will be the larger of the weight and the thrust.

@James ... thanks for your correction
